# mocking and testing directive with isolate scope containing ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a directive that I want to mock and test.  The directive has ngModel set to double binding and transclude true

```
scope: {'ngModel': '=' } 

transclude: true
```

The spec that I am to test is pretty straightforward.

```
$el.find('input').prop('checked', $scope.ngModel);
```

Inside of my unit tests I  created a beforeEach and created the directive to test  **ngModel=checked**

```
   element = angular.element("<div *directiveName* ><div><input type=\"checkbox\" ngModel=checked /> </div></div>");

        $rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile(element)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest(element);

        scope = element.isolateScope();
```

Usually I would set scope to equal element.scope(). I would call the **isolateScope()** method on this right?

I believed that since I am setting scope to equal the elements **isolateScope()** the spec should be as simple as

```
        expect(scope.ngModel).to.equal('checked');
```

However, **scope.ngModel** is undefined.  I am not sure what I am missing when I create the directive or call the test.  Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: does your directive has an isolated scope? try scope = element.isolateScope() || element.scope; to cover both scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the value into the element correctly.  It should be:

```
element = angular.element("<div *directiveName* ><div><input type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=checked /> </div></div>");
```

the change being ng-model instead of ngModel.

I would also recommend using a different name for your custom attribute in the directive because of the confusion with the built in angular directive.

Comment: I would if it was my directive to write.  I am simply testing it.  The ngModel is  exactly how they did it

Comment: so you can't rename the attribute, but you still need to have it be ng-model instead of ngModel in the test html

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I caught the camel casing error.  However, the ngModel is still undefined in my test.  Not sure what an additional step would be.

Comment: you also added ng-model to an element inside of the directive element instead of directly on it.  That could by why it's not picking it up